# How to add a text/input field into PDF on Mac

Tags: pdf, text-input

I have a PDF form where some manager should write down the relevant data. I want to add an text/input field to this PDF file to simplify this process - now it is just printed lines to fill by handwriting.

After I add the text field I send the PDF file to the manager.

Any suggestions, soft etc are welcome (Right now I have only the Preview  and a Google Docs account).

Answer (score -2):

For development of forms, get Acrobat Pro, and for using the forms, have your users using Acrobat Reader.

Important: Never, ever, ever use Preview.app for working with forms; Preview.app is a very sure tool to completely corrupt a PDF form.

Comment: 450$ ?? for a text field? hm...

Comment: I agree with Max. you want to edit a PDF, Acrobat is the gold standard. I believe there are others available for Mac tho, a quick search will turn them up. Also I've **never** had Preview corrupt a PDF

Comment: @SteveChambers: Then you never worked with fillable forms you had to send back for further processing using Preview.app.

Comment: Actually I have, many times, just never had a problem

Comment: Preview is fairly benign with most forms; generally they come back filled, but with all form fields locked and set to read-only. You can edit in Acrobat to unlock and change read settings. Of course, in many cases any scripting might get stripped, so there's that caveat...